# Post To Facebook message about my app

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, facebook

i am already got the fbconnect well and can show the dialog to post on my wall.

but now i want a post to be shown when the user logs in.

post a message that will be ready in `NSString` Format before.

how can i do it without the dialog box?

Comment: I am not sure I understood your question but if you want to post to the user's wall without showing a dialog box, I am not sure if that is really possible.